# How can I redeclare the same class method more than once in php?

Tags: php, html, database, class

I have a problem with my code. I have code like this:

```
<?php
     include('php/SelectHistory.php');
     include('php/SelectSmallHistoryUser.php');
     include('php/SelectSmallHistoryProject.php');
     include('php/SelectSmallHistoryFunctionality.php');

     $newHistoryRow = SelectHistory();

     echo "<table width='100%'>";

     if (count($newHistoryRow) > 0)
     {
         foreach ($newHistoryRow as $current)
         {
              $chosenUser = SelectSmallHistoryUser($current->userID);
              $chosenProject = SelectSmallHistoryProject($current->projectID);
              $chosenFunctionality = SelectSmallHistoryFunctionality($current->functionalityID);
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $chosenUser->fullName . " was busy with " . $chosenFunctionality->functionalityName . " on " . $chosenProject->projectName . " at " . $current->lastModifiedDate;
              echo "</tr>";
              unset($chosenUser);
              unset($chosenProject);
              unset($chosenFunctionality);
          }
      }
      else
      {
          echo "<tr><td>No History To Display.</td></tr>";
      }

      echo "</table>";
?>
```

The problem that I have with it is that within the loop, it declares a method which resides in a class. Now because it is working with data from a database, if the amount of things is more than one, I get a "Class already declared" error.

Is there a way I can fix this or is there another method I can use?

Comment: There is a way to fix this: *stop declaring/including classes from within the loop*. Which, by the way, is something you don't actually show here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way of creating class :

```
class TestClass {
    public $property;
    //some other properties
    function __construct($id) {
        $this->property=$id;
        //do some other stuff
    }
    //some other functions
}
```

And the right way of creating an instance of class is :

```
 $test = new TestClass($id);
```

Mind the `__construct()` function and the `new` keyword and try executing your script again.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new one i guess. `$var = new SelectHistory();`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating object like above you should do is, define a static function to get the data you want. You would be able to call the function as below without creating an object.

```
SelectSmallHistoryUser::getData($current->userID);
```

Creating objects withing a loop is not acceptable. [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 0):

Declaring or including classes in a loop is not good.
But check this : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php